# jstl не работает в tomcat 8

Tags: jsp, tomcat, jstl

Когда я на jsp-странице объявляю директиву:

```html
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

получаю исключение:

```
HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.index_jsp

type Exception report

message java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.index_jsp

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.index_jsp
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:176)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:375)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.index_jsp
java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:131)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:62)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:171)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:375)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/8.0.36 logs.

Apache Tomcat/8.0.36
```

мой pom.xml:

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>myTask</groupId>
    <artifactId>App</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>GuestApp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Подскажите: как исправить данную проблему. Спасибо.

Comment: Вы хотите jar или war на выходе получить?

Comment: war. а Это влияет на данный вопрос?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поставьте

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

Comment: Я, честно говоря, не знаю что помогло. т.к. вчера выбрасывало exception. Потом я пробовал добавлять разные зависимости из сотен тех, что находил на русском и английском stackoverflow. Теперь все нормально работает и с тем помником, который указан в вопросе и c любым из типов результатирующего файла: и war, и jar...

Comment: Попробуйте сделать clean и собрать ещё раз. По идее с jar не будет работать. Так как по умолчанию он не будет упаковывать библиотеки.

Comment: возможно, это звучит странно, но даже после clean у меня все работает с вчерашними настройками. Я заменил в помнике весь код на скопированный из своего же вчерашнего вопроса. Норм работа, ошибка воспроизводиться только если убрать оттуда jstl зависимость... Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: а вы чистили webapps у Tomcat? если там лежит ваше старое приложение, то там есть библиотека.

Comment: благодаря Вашему вопросу я немного разобрался с принцыпом работы Tomcat. До этого момента запускал приложение в Tomcat из под intellij IDEA и было фактически все равно что указано war or jar. Сам же по себе Tomcat мне вообще не дает возможности загрузить jar - only war. Я так понимаю: так и должно же быть?

Comment: war - это способ распространения веб-приложений на java. и war отличается от jar содержимым. я не уверен, что Tomcat проверяет расширение файла, но вот содержимое проверяет.

Comment: судя по описанию ошибки проверяет: _FAIL - File uploaded "TestApp.jar" must be a .war_